# Navbar selects two drawers at once if one path contains the other in Vue

Tags: vue.js, routes, navigation, sidebar

I'm creating an application in Vue.js with a sidebar.

In `v-list-item`, in the path `:to="link.route"`, I'm using the names for routes: `{ name: "dashboard" }`.

The problem occurs when the path to one link is contained in a link to the other path.
Eg. `path: '/'` (dashboard) is contained in `path: '/help'`.

If I click on `Help`, then both sidebar drawers are selected:

[image: Two sidebar items]

Template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer">
      <v-list nav dense>
        <v-list-item-group>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="link in links"
            :key="link.text"
            :to="link.route">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title class="white--text">{{
                link.text
              }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```html
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    drawer: true,
  }),
  computed: {
    links() {
      return [
        {
          text: "Dashboard",
          route: { name: "dashboard" },
        },
        {
          text: "Help",
          route: { name: "help" },
        },
      ];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Router:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Dashboard from '../views/Dashboard.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'dashboard',
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    path: '/help',
    name: 'help',
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding path `{ name: "dashboard", path:'/' }`in dashboard route declaration.

Code before:

```
    links() {
      return [
        {
          text: this.$i18n.t("navbar.dashboard"),
          route: { name: "dashboard"},
        },
        {
          text: this.$t("navbar.help"),
          route: { name: "help"},
        },
      ];
    },
```

Code after:

```
    links() {
      return [
        {
          text: this.$i18n.t("navbar.dashboard"),
          route: { name: "dashboard", path:'/' },
        },
        {
          text: this.$t("navbar.help"),
          route: { name: "help"},
        },
      ];
    },
```

It's not exactly what I wanted, but it solves the problem.